# Flutter Firestore StreamTransformer DocumentSnapshot error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was practice Flutter to develop a simple real time chat app with firestore, previous I using cloud_firestore 0.13.7 and working fine. After update to new version of cloud_firestore 0.14.0+2, there is a breaking changes in the code that I not sure how to modify it.

repository_service.dart

```
class RepositoryService {
final CollectionReference _usersCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getChatList(String id) {
    return _userChatsCollectionReference.doc(id).snapshots();
  }
}
```

chat_services.dart

```
class chat_services(){

RepositoryService _repositoryService = locator<RepositoryService>();

Stream<List<String>> getChatList(String id) {
    return _repositoryService.getChatList(id).transform(documentToChatListTransformer);
  }

  StreamTransformer documentToChatListTransformer = StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot, List<String>>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (DocumentSnapshot snapShot, EventSink<List<String>> sink) {
      if (snapShot.exists) {
        sink.add(snapShot.data.keys.toList());
      } else {
        sink.add([]);
      }
    }
  );

}
```

the error is **keys** which from function **documentToChatListTransformer** in chat_services.dart

> The getter 'keys' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>
> Function()'. Try importing the library that defines 'keys', correcting
> the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or
> field named 'keys'.dart(undefined_getter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `data` is a [method on DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html), not a property. You need to call the method with parenthesis:

```
snapShot.data().keys.toList()
```